# Regular expression for end of line phrase

Tags: php, regex

I am grabbing a block of text, and within this block there will be a line containing a phrase that ends with "WITH PASSWORD kEqHqPUd" where kEqHqPUd is a dynamically generated password. What is a simple regular expression for grabbing just the password within this?

I'm using PHP.

Comment: Have you tried to come up with your own?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
preg_match('/WITH PASSWORD (.*)$/im', $block, $matches);
//result in $matches[1]
```

The key is the ["m" modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how you define "*phrase that ends*"... But if you mean "*a sentence ends with the password, but could be followed by another sentence*", then a solution could be:

```
$text = <<<TEXT
This is some
text and there is a sentence that ends
with WITH PASSWORD kEqHqPUd. Is that
matched ?
TEXT;

$matches = array();
if (preg_match('/WITH PASSWORD ([\w\d]+)/', $text, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

This will only work, though, if the password only contains letters and/or numbers -- but it will work if there is something after "*the end of the phrase*".

If you meant that the password is the last thing in the whole string, you could use something like this:

```
$text = <<<TEXT
This is some
text and there is a sentence that ends
with WITH PASSWORD kEqHqPUd
TEXT;

$matches = array();
if (preg_match('/WITH PASSWORD (.+)$/m', $text, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

Note that the `$` sign means "*end of string*".

Comment: I confess the ambiguity did not occur to me, but I think the capital letters hinted that it was not actually flowing English text with proper sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that PHP accepts standard regex patterns, "WITH PASSWORD (.+)+$" should work, where the password will be placed in the first capture group.